# "Safe" dynamic cast?

Tags: c++, oop, casting

I'm familiar with how to do a dynamic cast in C++, as follows:

```
myPointer = dynamic_cast<Pointer*>(anotherPointer);
```

But how do you make this a "safe" dynamic cast?

Comment: What do you mean by "safe"?

Comment: Just check is myPointer non-null.

Comment: I suppose I mean, is this a potential point of failure? If so, how to prevent that?

Comment: Everything is a point of failure if you use it wrong.  What kinds of problems are you trying to avoid?

Comment: Ok, excellent, great tip @cbel

Comment: The logistical flow of the program is ok, I just want to make sure that if this dynamic_cast fails in some way, to halt execution or further processing with it.

Comment: @cbel so, does the dynamic_cast return NULL if unsuccessful?

Comment: and also @cbel, if you formulate your comment into an answer, I'd be glad to give you the checkmark.

Comment: If you use references then `dynamic_cast<Pointer&>(*anotherPointer);` then it will throw an exception on failure, you won't need to check for a null pointer.

Comment: @user1520427 So should these casts be run in try/catch blocks?

Comment: I think the only way you can make it 100% safe is if you use a shared/unique pointer. Or use a weak_ptr and lock it. Of course check if it's nullptr, afterwards as well.

Comment: @Ben I'm looking for something *very* basic. I think even a NULL check may do the trick.

Comment: @user3308043 Only if you use references - if a cast fails on a pointer then it will return a null pointer, if it fails on a reference it will throw an exception. It depends what you want really, if you don't want to check each cast for a non-null value, then use references. IF you don't want to catch exceptions, use pointers.

Comment: @user1520427 My code uses pointers. Do I check for NULL or is there another way to refer to null pointers?

Comment: @user3308043 Check the pointer is non-zero, or if you're using C++11 check it against `nullptr`.

Comment: @user1520427 I'm getting an error saying nullptr is only part of C++ 11, and NULL compiles ok. Is this a good way to go, just comparing the pointer against NULL?

Comment: @user3308043 Yep, or alternatively `if (myPointer) { // valid }` would work too.

Comment: If you don't want to throw, it's generally good to use `if (Derived* p = dynamic_cast<Derived*>(p_base)) ...use p... [else ...wasn't a Derived...]`.  No need to explicitly compare to `NULL` or `nullptr` and `p` can't be accidentally used outside the scope where it's known valid.

Comment: @TonyD Great, clean alternative.

Comment: @Ben: you often don't want to use a smart pointer for this, as the lifetime's already being managed by the pointer-to-base or caller, and the `dynamic cast` is just done to allow some type-specific operations to be invoked from a local scope.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When `dynamic_cast` cannot cast a pointer because it is not a complete object of the required class it returns a null pointer to indicate the failure. 
If `dynamic_cast` is used to convert to a reference type and the conversion is not possible, an exception of type bad_cast is thrown instead.

Comment: You imply to use a NULL check or exception-handling to remedy the issue, so thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Q** But how do you make this a "safe" dynamic cast?

**A** It will be a safe dynamic cast as long as the argument to `dynamic_cast` is a valid pointer (including NULL). If you pass a dangling pointer or a value that is garbage, then the call to `dynamic_cast` is not guaranteed to be safe. In fact, the best case scenario is that the run time system throws an exception and you can deal with it. The worst case scenario is that it is undefined behavior. You can get one behavior now and a different behavior next time.

Comment: Why would it throw an exception if you pass it a dangling pointer?

Comment: So should this be handled in a try/catch block?

Comment: Doing dynamic cast on a dangling pointer sounds like something that should be ub. The pointer _could_ point to something still valid.

Comment: I think this answer misses the point. Of course it's unsafe to do operations on dangling pointers, I think what the OP wants to know is if it will throw exceptions on bad data, and if not, what to check against.

Answer (score 0):

Most ways in which you might attempt to abuse `dynamic_cast` result in a compiler error (for example, trying to cast to a type that's not in a related polymorphic hierarchy).

There are also two runtime behaviours for times when you effectively use `dynamic_cast` to ask whether a particular pointer actually addresses an object of a specific derived type:

```
if (Derived* p = dynamic_cast<Derived*>(p_base))
{
    ...can use p in here...
}
else
    ...p_base doesn't point to an object of Derived type, nor anything further
       derived from Derived...

try
{
    Derived& d = dynamic_cast<Derived&>(*p_base);
    ...use d...
}
catch (std::bad_cast& e)
{
    ...wasn't Derived or further derived class...
}
```

The above is "safe" (defined behaviour) as long as `p_base` is either `nullptr`/`0` or really does point to an object derived from `Base`, otherwise it's Undefined Behaviour.

Additionally, there is a runtime-unsafe thing you can do with a `dynamic_cast<>`, yielding Undefined Behaviour:

- Standard 12.7/6: *"If the operand of the dynamic_cast refers to the object under construction or destruction and the static type of the operand is not a pointer to or object of the constructor or destructor’s own class or one of its bases, the dynamic_cast results in undefined behavior.*".  The Standard provides an example to illustrate this.